# Extract Image from URL - jpeg only - a different approach

Tags: php, dom

I'm trying to extract images from a web page.

I am using the follolwing code but it gives no output although i know there is some there (used ebay page as example)

```
$html = "http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/190706137456?_trkparms=clkid%3D1088812801530482649&_qi=RTM944765";
$dom = new domDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
echo $image->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Further to this is it possible to just extract jpg images, and then further, only images above a certain height/width size?

I've been using simple_html_dom recently but it fails a lot of the time and I find it slow.

Is there a way, for example, instead of looking for 'img' and 'src' to just find anything that ends '.jpg' the strip everything before 'http://...etc etc..'

Answer (score 0):

Try using $dom->loadHTMLFile() instead of $dom->loadHTML.  So...

```
$html = "http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/190706137456?_trkparms=clkid%3D1088812801530482649&_qi=RTM944765";
$dom = new domDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile($html);
```

You can filter image types (and get only the file name) in your foreach() loop.  Try something like this:

```
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
  $filename = basename($image->getAttribute('src'));
  $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  if ($ext == 'jpg') {
     echo $filename . '<br>';
  }
}
```

You can also filter by image width and height, but it appears to be weird with how it finds the width and height.  You'd imagine that by using these attributes...

```
$width = $image->getAttribute('width');
$height = $image->getAttribute('height');
```

...It would spit out the width="xxx" and height="yyy"...but it doesn't.  It looks like it takes the style attributes instead.  So keep that in mind.  That being said, you can use a similar solution like above for width and height too.  Like so:

```
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
   $filename = basename($image->getAttribute('src'));
   $width = $image->getAttribute('width');
   $height = $image->getAttribute('height');
   $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   if ($ext == 'jpg' && ($width > 20 && $height > 10)) {
      echo $filename . "($width x $height)" . '<br>';
   }
}
```

Hopefully that works for you.  Here's everything, in case you need it:

```
$html = "http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/190706137456?_trkparms=clkid%3D1088812801530482649&_qi=RTM944765";
$dom = new domDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
   $filename = basename($image->getAttribute('src'));
   $width = $image->getAttribute('width');
   $height = $image->getAttribute('height');
   $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   if ($ext == 'jpg' && ($width > 20 && $height > 10)) {
      echo $filename . "($width x $height)" . '<br>';
   }
}
```